# hid-generic messages during boot since upgrade from 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

since i upgraded to 16.04 from 15.10 my boot screen displays a full screen of  lines of:

```
hid-generic 0003:0B505:17FD.0008: unknown main item tag 0x0
```

each line preceded by a a string of digits like "[   12.248908]"

any ideas what this is? how to fix it?
thanks